# Get Checkout Steps In Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to give a div a certain height according to the checkout step. here's what I've got:

```
<ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">

<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>

<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>

    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
            <span class="number"><?php echo $i ?></span>
            <h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        </div>
```

Here's how what I'm trying to do:

```
<ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps-<?php echo $_stepId ?>">

<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>

<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>

    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
            <span class="number"><?php echo $i ?></span>
            <h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        </div>
```

It doesn't work. How can I call this like this somehow? Thanks

Comment: If it's for custom markup or styling then add an extra class to the tags, try to avoid changing the default markup unless you know how the OPC works

Comment: I need this div to be a different size for each step. I can't add a class because it will be for all the steps.

Comment: Side note: you might get a better response on the Magento StackExchange site